# Зависимые слова

Tags: общие-вопросы

Зависимое слово - это слово, к которому задается вопрос от главного слова. Например, в словосочетании "умный парень" слово "парень" - главное слово. Парень какой? Умный. Но почему мы не можем задать вопрос умный кто? парень ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, конечно, очень странно вопрос сформулировали... Что значит "почему не можем"? Во-первых, в каком-то смысле как раз можем. Вы это и сделали. Только он не будет вопросом от главного к зависимому. Ну а во-вторых, вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему", обычно бессмысленны изначально. Советую как-то по-другому их задавать.

Судя по всему, ваш вопрос должен звучать как-то так. **Какое слово в словосочетании следует считать главным и как его отличить от зависимого?**

Проблемы тут нет. Надо просто понять, что такое **"главное слово"**. Главным в словосочетании называется не просто слово, от которого можно задать вопросы к другими словам, главным считается слово, которое определяет основной смысл словосочетания, его значение. На то оно и главное. А зависимое слово лишь уточняет значение главного. 
Что касается вопроса, который можно задавать от главного к зависимому, то имеется в виду не всякий вопрос, а лишь уточняющий. В вашем примере "парень" является главным словом, поскольку оно определяет смысл словосочетания. И от него можно задать *уточняющий* вопрос к зависимому.

Правильно будет сказать, что при разборе словосочетания необходимо сначала найти в нем главное слово - исходя из представлений об основном смысле высказывания. И только потом можно убедиться, что от него задаются вопросы к зависимым словам.

Другими словами, возможность такого вопроса является не определением для главного и зависимого слов, а лишь признаком, которым можно и нужно пользоваться, но который сам по себе не отражает сути этих понятий. К сожалению, в школьных методиках про этот момент часто забывают.